# iOS: Automate speaking text in the original language

Tags: ios, siri

I get messages in multiple languages. My iOS language is English. I know iOS is able to auto-detect a language, because when it works as expected when I select the text and tap "Speak".

However when Siri gets a message it will just say "James sent a message that's not in English".

I'd like to add a shortcut that would try to detect the language and speak it. Is that at all possible? I searched through the different available automations in the Shortcut app and couldn't find anything.